Prove that, there exists infinite $n$ so that $n$ divides $2^n + 1$
Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $n | 2^n+1$. Prove that, there are infinite solutions My attempt: My intuition was to show that $n=3^k$ for any positive integer $k$ works, which I tried to do by induction but got stuck half-way

See art of problem solving.

Another proof has been given here: $n=3^s$ keeps $\frac{2^n+1}{n}$ an integer, where $s$ is natural number which can be verified as follows:
As  $2$ is a primitive root of $3^s$ for all $s\ge 1,$  so, if $n=3^s$, $\operatorname{ord}_{(3^s)}2=\phi(3^s)=2\cdot 3^{s-1}\implies 2^{\frac{\phi(n)}2}\equiv -1\pmod n$
Now, $\frac{\phi(n)}2=3^{s-1}\implies 2^{3^{s-1}}\equiv -1\pmod {3^s}$.
This implies $$(2^{3^{s-1}})^3\equiv -1\implies 2^{3^s}\equiv -1\pmod {3^s}.$$
